# Cmake did find `A_library`, but when `make` it tells `library not found for A_library`?

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to build a project which needs FLANN. When executing `cmake`, it shows

```
-- Checking for module 'flann'
--   Found flann, version 1.9.1
-- FLANN found (include: /usr/local/Cellar/flann/1.9.1_7/include, lib: flann;flann_cpp)
-- FLANN found (include: /usr/local/Cellar/flann/1.9.1_7/include, lib: flann;flann_cpp)
```

But I got `ld: library not found for -lflann` when executing `make`.

I'm using cmake 3.15.1 on MacOS.

The `CMakeLists.txt` shows below.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(pcl_visualizer)

# init_qt: Let's do the CMake job for us
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) # For meta object compiler
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON) # Resource files
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON) # UI files
set(Qt5_DIR "/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.0/lib/cmake/Qt5")

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED Widgets)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL 1.7.1 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set(project_SOURCES main.cpp pclviewer.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${project_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} Qt5::Widgets)
```

Comment: Do a verbose build (`make VERBOSE=1`) and check the full linker options. Are the correct `-L` options specifying the path to the library there? Are there some options you missed adding (how about `${VTK_LIBRARIES}`)?

Comment: can't see any usage of `flann` in that file?

Comment: @Alan Birtles. It is a demo from [pcl document](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/qt_visualizer.php#id2). And yes I see nothing about `flann` in codes.

Comment: @Some programmer dude. I did a verbose build and got `/usr/local/lib/libqhull_p.dylib -lflann -lflann_cpp`. What does it mean? Does it mean it actually find `flann`? But why does it print `ld: library not found for -lflann`?